# Simple Iterations

Tags: c#, algorithm, equation

could you help me with the method of simple iterations, I wrote an algorithm but for some reason it tends to infinity, Newton's algorithm solves this task without problems, but there is a problem with this algorithm ... Can you tell me what needs to be done to do it its fully functional?

x^3+3*x^2-2=0

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Solve(-3.0));    
    }

    static double function(double x) => Math.Pow(x, 3) + 3 * Math.Pow(x, 2) - 2;

    static double Solve(double x)
    {
        double eps = 0.000001;
        double y;
        double b;
        do
        {
            y = function(x);

            b = Math.Abs(y - x);

            x = y;

        }while (b >= eps);

        return y;
    }
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the formula using parenthesis? I have trouble mind computing what gets multiplied first and stuff

Comment: Why should repeatedly applying the function converge to a fixed point?

Comment: What you're implementing here isn't [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Your algorithm, simply put, isn't going to find solutions to the equation. If you used `Math.Cos(x)` as the `function`, you *would* calculate [something interesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number).

Comment: No, I don’t need Newton’s algorithm, I said that they can easily solve such a problem ... I just need an algorithm of simple iterations

Comment: function(-3) = -2; function(-2) = 2; function(2) = 18.. function(18) = 6802. function(6802) = 314848323218 -- this chain does not converge

Comment: @JeroenMostert I did not quite understand what you mean, according to the condition of the assignment, I must solve this 3rd order equation by the method of simple iterations.

Comment: What do they mean by "simple iterations"?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, I understand that the algorithm is not compressed, that's why I asked for help ... The one who gave the task has no idea how to do it.

Comment: Maybe something like `for (var i = -3; i < 3; i++) Console.WriteLine(function(i));` and hope the best that we find a 0.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @KlausGütter I don't know how it's called in the original, but in Russian it's called the simple iteration method

Comment: @BlankList you can just switch language in wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration =)

Comment: @GuruStron at first it just seemed to me that these algorithms were different, but probably this is the same

Comment: Perhaps I need to somehow transform the equation before solving it with iterations?

Comment: You are just computing f^n(x)... Newton's method need to use the derivative of it to converge to the 0 of the function. Read about Newton-Raphson's method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I don’t need Newton’s method, I formulated my thought incorrectly, I meant that I managed to solve a similar equation with Newton’s method without problems, but with the method of simple iterations (fixed-point iteration) no

Comment: Oh fixed point...sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first is that fixed point methods solve problems of the form `f(x) = x` and not `f(x) = 0`.

You could solve that by trying to solve `x = x^3+3*x^2-x-2`, but then you run into the second problem.  And that is that unless you guess very close to the answer, `x^3` is going to grow on every iteration and you'll go off to infinity.

Therefore you need to find a problem of the form `f(x) = x` to solve where `f` tends to converge, not diverge.

I would suggest you rewrite it to `x^3 = -3*x^2 + 2` and then take cube roots so you're now solving `x = (-3 x^2 + 2)^(1/3)`.  C# may not like fractional powers of negative numbers, so you'll need to check the sign and manually deal with that knowing that `(-y)^(1/3) = -y^(1/3)`.

---

Here is sample code in Python showing the idea.

```
def iteration (x):
    y = -3 * x*x + 2
    if y < 0:
        return - (-y)**(1/3)
    elif 0 < y:
        return y**(1/3)
    else:
        return 0


x = 100
for i in range(100):
    print(i, x)
    x = iteration(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: There was a problem at any approximation it gives out 1, but it should be at -3 2.7

Comment: @BlankList That is a bug in your code.  I just updated with a working example in Python which converges to -2.732050807569 and then hits roundoff bugs in the calculation.

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me how to find the 2nd and 3rd root, the first one can be searched without problems

Comment: @BlankList Unless you are lucky, this technique can only find roots where the derivative is in the range `(0, -1)`.

Comment: That is, with this method I can’t find the 3rd root, which is approximately 0.7320508075688773?

Comment: With the first approximation any other than -1 and 1, it is easy to find the first root, with the value -1 or 1 it was possible to find the second root which is equal to -1, and the 3rd root cannot be found in any way

Comment: @BlankList With this particular function, yes.  You don't converge near the third root.  With another function, you can converge.  Newton's method, for example, can be looked at as a fixed point method which converges at all roots.

Comment: I understood, thank you, yes, just with Newton there were 3 convergences and therefore I found all 3 roots, but unfortunately the task required this solution method ... Well, it turns out that the 3rd root cannot be found by this method, this is a problem of a specific function in combination with this method.

Comment: sorry for my english